# ASP.NET-MVC not rendering View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've a menu list displayed in the browser as a list of anchor tags. When a user clicks I'm passing its id to controller using ajax as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        var Url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:Url,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: this.id })
            })
        });
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ShopOnline</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="soContainer">
        <div id="soCategories">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="everything">Everything</a>
                        <ul id="catUL">
                            @foreach (var c in Model.CategoriesWithCount)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <a id="@c.Key" href ="@Url.Action("ListOfBrandNames","Home")">@c.Key</a>
                                    (@c.Value)
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-inline" id="topMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Bought Before</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this id is passed down to the following action method as parameter to get a list of string(i.e., brand names) to send to a `View` as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListOfBrandNames(string id)
    {
        var result = db.Items.Where(x => x.Category.Name.Equals(id)).Select(x => x.BrandID).ToList();
        var ListOfBrands = db.Brands.Where(t => result.Contains(t.BrandID)).ToList();

        var brandNanes = ListOfBrands.Select(f => f.Name.ToString()).ToList();
        return View(brandNanes);
    }
```

Above code successfully passes desired list of string to following `View` as:

```
@model List<string>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ListOfBrandNames</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <td>
                    @i.ToString();
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

for loop in `View` successfully runs for all elements in the list but program is breaking with a `404 Error` in the browser when the list ends in the for loop. Am I calling the `View` incorrectly or something?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?  I don't see how this page could render output *and* return a 404 error.

Comment: I'm checking everything in `Debug` mode that for loop in the `View` is processing list of string received from `Controller`. Suppose, in this list, if I've 3 string items, for loop runs 3 iterations and when it runs for the 4th iteration to check if there are any more string items in the list, program is breaking...rendering `404 error` in browser.

Comment: Something else must be happening in the program as well, not shown here.  All you have here is a `List<string>` and a `foreach` loop over that list.  That, by itself, wouldn't cause the described problem.  Do you have *any* other code which is adding more complexity to your page?  And how is "the program breaking" specifically?  Is there an exception?  How is that exception becoming a 404 error?

Comment: The only things that stick out is that you could help razor a bit by specifically denoting html within a code-block by using _@:_ (example: _@:<td>_). Also remove the semicolon from _@i.ToString();_ (and ToString() is not needed).

Comment: when you debug `@foreach (var i in Model)` what you are getting in this Model

Comment: Can you share browser error screenshot with url

Comment: Do you have HTTPGet controller if you dont have you get this error

Comment: @David - I'm passing a string to above action method from a View using `ajax`. I'm adding that view code to my question in a minute for you.

Comment: @erdiyılmaz - As given in the above, `[HttpPost]` is being used in the code because it is accepting a string from a `View` as parameter sent to it by an `ajax` call.

Comment: @RK: *"As given in the above"* - There is no AJAX in the code shown above.  Please provide code which actually demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically in that code where the problem is occurring.

Comment: @David - I've finished updating this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making two separate requests when you click on a link.  First is your AJAX request, which is succeeding.  But, since you're clicking on a link, you're *also* making a standard GET request when your browser tries to follow that link.  This *second* request is failing, because GET is not allowed on that controller action.

You could cancel the default request in your JavaScript code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the rest of your code...
});
```

Or you could maintain your current pattern of using `#` in your links and store the URL in something other than `href`.  Something like:

```
<a id="@c.Key" href="#" data-href="@Url.Action("ListOfBrandNames","Home")">@c.Key</a>
```

and in your JavaScript:

```
var Url = $(this).data("href");
```

Or perhaps replace the link entirely with a button (which would be more semantically correct I suspect):

```
<button type="button" id="@c.Key" data-href="@Url.Action("ListOfBrandNames","Home")">@c.Key</button>
```

That way it wouldn't have a default action (be aware of any `<form>` tags involved as well of course) but would just be used to invoke a client-side operation, which is what you're doing in the code anyway.

---

Either way is up to you, but the main point is that you need to prevent the browser from making the GET request to your POST-only action.

Comment: Still getting a `404 error` in the browser with `e.preventDefault();` applied and having `href="#"`.

Comment: `<button type="button" id="@c.Key" data-href="@Url.Action("ListOfBrandNames","Home")">@c.Key</button>` might be one of the ways to go here.

Comment: @RK: Can you provide your updated code?  When you use your browser's debugging tools to capture and persist all of the network requests, what requests are made?  I agree that a button is likely the best approach, as it's meant to perform client-side operations in the first place so you wouldn't be in a position where you need to override default behavior at all.

Comment: It seems it was not the href="#" default call that was causing the issue as this issue is still persisting after we have eliminated it by applying `e.preventDefault();`. Program is still breaking after the for loop finishes processing the list given to it in the View.

Comment: To add more, Network tab in chrome developer tool is giving a 200 OK green status for the call that is made when an anchor is clicked. Server side code is also running as expected until the very last when it is time to render the view.

Comment: @RK: You can make all the assumptions you like, but without seeing the updated code there's little anybody here can do to help.  Make sure you fully examine all network requests being made by your browser, because if the symptoms haven't changed then it's a pretty strong indicator that your client-side code is still making two separate requests.  Unless you have some other code not shown here which explicitly returns a 404 response, the fact that the server-side code is reached at all means it's *not* a 404.

Comment: You're right. After we have applied `e.preventDefault();` no `404` is thrown in the browser this time. Browser stays on the same page on which the click request is made after code completes its execution cycle and so the url in the browser remains the same when it should instead change to the desired webpage url if all of it is making sense to you.

Comment: @RK: No, that's not making sense to me.  So the problem has been solved?  And now you're working on an entirely different problem?  If that's the case then it sounds like this question has been successfully answered and it's time to post a new question rather than add confusion to this question.

Comment: I'd have loved to mark this as answer if it had completely solved the issue given in the title of this question. It seems my code was wrong having given two calls to one click event which has now been corrected with your pointing it out and demonstrating how to eliminate it. But since ASP.NET-MVC still not routing to the desired view is still persisting, I cannot mark this as answer. I'm updating this question code with the code snap-shots for you if you're still interested in solving it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RK: What do you mean by "still not routing to the desired view"?  You're making an AJAX call, the server-side code is correctly handling that call and returning the view, but in your JavaScript code you're not doing anything with that returned result.  What do you want to do with that returned result?  Why aren't you doing it?  If you want to direct the browser to a new page then you don't want to use AJAX at all, just use a link or a form post instead.  You seem to be continually clouding the issue here.

Comment: You have pretty much clarified everything related to this issue in this last comment of yours. I just learned that if i want to display a new page, i don't need ajax. Thanks a lot brother David. You rock.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using an a tag to do what you should be doing with a button tag.

1. you can just use a button tag instead of an a tag, you may have to use some css to make it look like an a tag

2.you dont have to put the URL in the href property of the a tag if you dont actually want to you use it like a regular a tag.

for example you can place it in the data-href attribute

```
 <a id="@c.Key" data-href ="@Url.Action("ListOfBrandNames","Home")">@c.Key</a>
...
var Url = $(this).attr("data-href");
```

this will prevent the a tag from trying to navigate to that url when you click on it.
note that this may course the cursor icon to change, you can fix that by setting `href="#"` or  `style="cursor:pointer"`